# Does's CPU process could determine the speed potential of application

Tags: java, database, multithreading, cpu

I have two hardware. One is sitting in the front, receving user's input(Server A), the other is backend with database (Server B). Both Server using Java and multi processors. Server A talk to Server B by some proprietary protocol. When I do performance teseting, I notice server A's CPU consumption is not as big as server B (Java process with DB). Can I make decision that Server A is faster than server B? Or Server has more potential to run faster than server B. In the other ways, what's the relation between CPU load/consumption percentage with application speed?

Comment: What is *application speed* anyway? Application A runs faster than application B because it has more power? nay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two machines are running different software then the CPU usage tells you nothing.

Measuring software performance is *hard*. You can't look at simple numbers like CPU usage. You also need to look at disk usage, network I/O, memory consumption and a whole range of other factors. Maybe machine A is I/O bound, or maybe it's waiting for machine B to respond to a request, or maybe it really *is* a faster machine.